# Change the name of a file right before uploaded to server

Tags: android, image, file

I need to upload an image to my server under a specific name, but ideally, I would like to still keep image stored on the device under the original file name. This is what I tried:

```
myImageFile.renameTo(new File("mobileimage.jpg"));
```

but when the file was uploaded to the server, it did not appear to have my new name. Here is the full code that uploads the image to the server:

```
        DefaultHttpClient mHttpClient;
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    try {
        myImageFile.renameTo(new File("mobileimage.jpg"));

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite/mobile/image");

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
        multipartEntity.addPart("userID", new StringBody(Constants.userID));
        multipartEntity.addPart("uniqueMobileID", new StringBody(Constants.uniqueMobileID));
        multipartEntity.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(myImageFile));
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

        HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        Log.d(TAG, "response: " + responseBody);
        return responseBody;

    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can I change the file name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [constructor](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html#FileBody%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) of FileBody that takes the fileName as an argument

Answer (score 1):

Try using the other implementation of [addPart](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html#addPart%28org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart%29) when attaching the file, so that you may add the filename field to the HTTP request. Something like this:

```
FormBodyPart userFile = new FormBodyPart("userfile", new FileBody(myImageFile));
userFile.addField("filename","NEWNAMEOFILE.jpg");
multipartEntity.addPart(userFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible renameTo() is returning false?  You should check your return values, especially with renameTo().